# Django Template - 2 HTML Tables Need them to match

Tags: html, css, django

I've created the following tables that are dynamically altered depending on different things.  The column widths are all calculated and I've output them inside the cells as well as into the width style.  I've used 2 tables in this manner so that it behaves as if the top piece is locked and the bottom moves.
I can not get these tables to line up.  I've included a picture with percents and one with pixels.  They line up better with percentages but I still want to them to as close to lined up as possible.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your `borders` are messing up your calculations. Top row doesn't have any cells so no border. So when you're setting `1200px` for example, you need to calculate each cell `width` including border. Which won't be the case with css. So each cell has for example `1px border`, you'll end up with an offset. And since you have a couple of cells without border in second table as well, it gets even more messed up.

What you probably have right now is, in first table, is a top row of `1200px` plus `1px` per `border` because table will auto fit to `width` of the cells. And on second table, you it'll be a bit less than top table because first row has some merged cells.
In second table, probably the opposite, you'll have a top table at 100% for first row, then second row doesn't have enough place to include `border` so your last 10% won't be a real 10%. And in second table, it'll be a bit better but still a bit short because of the merged cells.

What you could do is temporarily set `border` to `none` to see if this is indeed the problem.

If this is the problem, you can use jQuery `outerWidth()` to set your dimensions instead of using css. `OuterWidth` sets the width including `border` and padding, so it'll apply correct `css` to get the proper `width`.

See http://api.jquery.com/outerwidth/#outerWidth-value

Comment: Had not thought of this but I removed the borders and it still did not match up.  Thanks for the suggestion